# Recording microphone input with pyaudio fails

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to record input from several microphones using pyaudio but the recording is failing. I have built a test script based which attempts to read 10 seconds of audio input. However, the reading function returns immediately while I would expect to wait for the required time. The wav file the script creates is the correct length, however, the data within the wav file is predominately zeroes. I have tried several microphones, different hostApis and different data rates with no luck. I am running the latest pyaudio library version, `0.2.13` on Windows 10. I have checked my microphone privacy restrictions where desktop apps are allowed to access the microphone, and the correct python executable is shown to have accessed a microphone at an appropriate time.

I would be grateful for any advice.

The code I am using is as follows:

```py
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16  # Data format
CHANNELS = 1  # Mono audio
RATE = 44100  # Sample rate
CHUNK = 1024  # Frames per buffer
RECORD_SECONDS = 10  # Duration to record, adjust as needed

name_filter = 'UMM-6'
host_api_filter = pyaudio.paDirectSound

# Create a PyAudio instance
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def record_audio(device_index):
    device_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(device_index)
    print(f"Recording started for device {device_info.get('name')} ({device_index}) hostAPI {device_info.get('hostApi')} rate {RATE} channels {CHANNELS} format {FORMAT}")

    # Start the stream
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                    input_device_index=device_index)

    frames = []
    for _ in range(0, int((RATE * RECORD_SECONDS) / CHUNK)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    # Stop the stream
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    
    # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
    with wave.open(f"recording_{device_index}.wav", 'wb') as wf:
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))

    print(f"Recording finished for device {device_index}")

# Get a list of microphones
microphones = [idx for idx in range(p.get_device_count())
                if (device_info := p.get_device_info_by_index(idx)) and
                device_info.get('maxInputChannels') > 0 and
                name_filter in device_info.get('name') and
                ((host_api_filter == 0) or (device_info.get('hostApi') == host_api_filter))]

for mic in microphones:
    record_audio(mic)

p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to anyone, I swapped to use the `sounddevice` library using a variation of the following code and that worked without any issues:

```py
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write


HOSTAPI_FILTER = 'DirectSound'  # The name of the host API (driver) to use
NAME_FILTER = 'UMM-6'  # The name of the microphone to use
RATE = 44100  # Sample rate
DURATION = 5  # Duration to record
CHANNELS = 1  # Mono audio

# Find the host API matching the required filter
matching_hostapis = [idx for idx, h in enumerate(sd.query_hostapis()) if HOSTAPI_FILTER in h['name']]
if not matching_hostapis:
    raise ValueError(f'Hostapi matching name filter ({NAME_FILTER}) not found.')

idx_h = matching_hostapis[0]

matching_devices = [device for device in sd.query_devices()
                    if device['max_input_channels'] > 0
                    and NAME_FILTER in device.get('name')
                    and device['hostapi'] == idx_h]

if not matching_devices:
    raise ValueError(f'Device matching name filter ({NAME_FILTER}) not found.')

input_device = matching_devices[0]

# data recorded as 'float32' by default with +1.0 and -1.0 as the maximum and minimum values, respectively
data: np.ndarray = sd.rec(int(DURATION * RATE), samplerate=RATE, channels=CHANNELS, device=input_device["index"])

# Wait for the recording to finish
sd.wait()

# Save as WAV file
write("output.wav", RATE, data)
```